How can I write a heif image to a byte array with libheif?
I'm translating the libheif to pascal code using a dll, for this Delphi library. And I have been able to translate most needed functions, with the sole exception of writing a heif image to a byte array.
Reading a heif image as so is very simple to do, with the help of heif_context_read_from_memory. But there is no equivalent heif_context_write_to_memory function.
According to this issue. The library should be able to write a heif image using heif_context_write and providing a writing callback. And I have been able to successfully add such a implementation. Which is as follows:
const
  InputFile = 'C:\Test\sample.heic';
  OutputFile = 'output.heic';

var
  databytes: PByte;
  writer: THeifWriter;

var
  ctx: PHeifContext;
  imageHandle: PHeifImageHandle;
  encoder: PHeifEncoder;

  FImage: PHeifImage;
  FDataStride: integer;
begin
  // Allocate context
  ctx := heif_context_alloc();
  try
    // Make new memory instance
    heif_context_read_from_file(ctx, @AnsiString(InputFile)[1], nil).ErrRaise;

    // Get primary image
    heif_context_get_primary_image_handle(ctx, imageHandle).ErrRaise;
    try
      // Decode image
      heif_decode_image(imageHandle, FImage, THeifColorspace.colorspace_RGB, THeifChroma.chroma_interleaved_RGB, nil).ErrRaise;

      // Read plane
      heif_image_get_plane(FImage, THeifChannel.channel_interleaved, FDataStride);
    finally
      heif_image_handle_release(imageHandle);
    end;
  finally
    heif_context_free( ctx );
  end;

  // Encode
  ctx := heif_context_alloc();
  try
    // Crete encoder
    heif_context_get_encoder_for_format(ctx, THeifCompressionFormat.compression_HEVC, encoder).ErrRaise;
    try
      // Set quality
      heif_encoder_set_lossless(encoder, true).ErrRaise;

      // Encode
      heif_context_encode_image(ctx, FImage, encoder, nil, nil).ErrRaise;
    finally
      heif_encoder_release(encoder);
    end;

    // Write
    databytes := AllocMem(sizeof(byte));
    databytes^ := 123;

    writer.writer_api_version := 1;
    writer.write := writer_write;
    heif_context_write(ctx, writer, databytes);
  finally
    heif_context_free(ctx);
  end;

And the callback procedure:
function TForm1.writer_write(ctx: PHeifContext; const data: Pointer;
  size: cardinal; userdata: Pointer): THeifError;
var
  value: int64;
  MemoryZone: PByte;
begin
  // Allocate memory
  MemoryZone := AllocMem(size);
  try
    Move(data, MemoryZone, size);
  finally
    FreeMem(MemoryZone, size);
  end;

  // Result
  Result := THeifError.Create(THeifErrorNum.heif_error_Invalid_input);
end;

But the Move() procedure in the callback gives me an error. And the size cardinal always seems to be a bit random.
And It's not the encoder of the file. They are both read correctly. If I use heif_context_write_to_file(ctx, @AnsiString(OutputFile)[1]) instead of heif_context_write, the image is saved correctly.
I've scoured many examples and looked at the documentation. But everything I find is a bit lacking in explications on how that callback procedure even works.
And now I'm out of clues on what to do next.

Please do not post vague problem descriptions like gives me an error. Instead, post the complete, exact error message. It's on the screen right in front of you, and it contains relevant information that may help us answer your question. gives me an error is about as helpful as saying my car's not working or I don't feel well. We need details here.

@KenWhite My mistake. The error was vague by itself and provided no additional information. It was just an standard access violation error

Then that's not an error. It's an access violation, and the message for it contains information that can be useful in identifying the problem, giving us a place to look. ALWAYS include the complete, exact error message, whether it makes sense to you or not. You're asking us to help you solve your problem, and it's in your best interest to make it as easy as possible for us to do so by providing the relevant details that you have.

BTW, Delphi makes it extremely easy to get the message as text. When you see the dialog, just press Ctrl+C, which creates a copy of the message in the clipboard. You can then paste that directly into your post as a block quote. If you're running under the debugger, the Copy button on the exception dialog does the same thing.

The function DoWrite should be declared as class function DoWrite(ctx: PHeifContext; const data: Pointer; size: cardinal; userdata: Pointer): THeifError; static;
If it is a regular method, then Delphi includes a hidden parameter that refers to the Delphi class instance. When declared as a static function this hidden parameter is omitted.
In theory, you could just skip the ctx parameter in the callback function, but  then you have the risk that you will crash if this function refers to anything in the class. So the class static function is a cleaner solution.

By any chance this hidden parameter what's used for the Self. calling?

Yes, that is where the value for Self comes from.

Look at declaration of Move():
procedure Move(const Source; var Dest; Count: NativeInt);

Note untyped arguments which require using data variables rather than their addresses (a compiler gets data address itself). So this should solve this issue:
Move(PByte(data)^, PByte(MemoryZone)^, size);

Or use MoveMemory() with your pointers (note reversed parameter order!)
MoveMemory(MemoryZone, data, size);

Moreover, your callback procedure seems does nothing -  it copies data into MemoryZone but frees MemoryZone immediately. What logic do you mean here?

Unfortunately, that does not change anything.
From what I recall, I did try with ^, but I removed that character in an attempt to fix this. Both times an Access Violation error occurs.
The reason my callback procedure does nothing is because I first need to be able to read the data the procedure receives, so I did not get ahead of myself and first tried, well, moving the memory from the callback.

Update
As said by Sebastian Z in his answer, now marked as the solution, class methods include a hidden additional parameter referring to the class instance. This is a procedure of object.
The correct fix was to declare the callback as a regular procedure type, as follows:
THeifWriteFunc = function(ctx: PHeifContext; const data: Pointer; size: cardinal; userdata: Pointer): THeifError;

As a callback is defined in the class like:
class function DoWrite(ctx: PHeifContext; const data: Pointer; size: cardinal; userdata: Pointer): THeifError; static;

Do note that the procedure must be of the static type.
Finally, the actual procedure will be writted like:
function DoWrite(ctx: PHeifContext; const data: Pointer; size: cardinal;
  userdata: Pointer): THeifError;
var
  Stream: TStream;
begin
  Stream := TStream(userdata);

  // Write
  try
    Stream.Write(Data^, Size);
  except
    // Success
    Result := THeifError.Create(THeifErrorNum.heif_error_Decoder_plugin_error,
      THeifSuberrorCode.heif_suberror_Unspecified);
    Exit;
  end;

  // Success
  Result := THeifError.Create(THeifErrorNum.heif_error_Ok);
end;

The original answer
I have figured It out. The code itself was not the problem, but It was a matter of the procedure declaration in the libheif.dll library.
The writer_write callback should be defined as follows:
function THeifImage.DoWrite(const data: Pointer; size: cardinal;
  userdata: Pointer): THeifError;

instead of
function TForm1.writer_write(ctx: PHeifContext; const data: Pointer;
  size: cardinal; userdata: Pointer): THeifError;

The callback should not include the ctx value, which is a pointer to the heif context.
I'm unsure why that is. It could be because I'm using a slightly older version of the library, and the function was changed in a later version.
As of this issue and of this file in the library, the callback contains the ctx value.
The finalized code for writing the heif image to a memory stream is now:
// Start writing process
writer.writer_api_version := 1;
writer.write := DoWrite;
heif_context_write(ctx, writer, Stream).ErrRaise;

Where Stream is a TStream.
And the callback is declared under a class as follows:
function DoWrite(const data: Pointer; size: cardinal;
  userdata: Pointer): THeifError;
var
  Stream: TStream;
begin
  Stream := TStream(userdata);

  // Write
  try
    Stream.Write(Data^, Size);
  except
    // Success
    Result := THeifError.Create(THeifErrorNum.heif_error_Decoder_plugin_error,
      THeifSuberrorCode.heif_suberror_Unspecified);
    Exit;
  end;

  // Success
  Result := THeifError.Create(THeifErrorNum.heif_error_Ok);
end;

